# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working on iOS

Tags: html, ios, twitter-bootstrap

I've run into a problem where my dropdown isn't working in iOS. It works perfectly fine on desktop, but whenever I load up my site on my iPhone, the dropdown menu is nonexistent. Here is my html:

```
<div class='container visible-xs hidden-md'>
 <div class='row well well-sm mobile-well'>
  <div class='col-md-12 text-center dropdown'>
    <h4 class="dropdown-toggle explore" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdownMenu1" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Explore <span class='caret'></span></h4>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Home</a></li>
      <li class='divider'></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Menu</a></li>
      <li class='divider'></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">About</a></li>
      <li class='divider'></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-link">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or not, but any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: could i know your iphone and ios version?

Comment: @Ray I'm using an iphone 4s with the latest iOS and my girlfriend is using an iPhone 6s and had the same problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked this problem ( use my iPhone6 , latest iOS )

"Explore and caret" is visible but isn't work dropdown-menu. cause i forgot to add js code.
In my point of view, you have to check your js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown();
});
```

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-1

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'll check my JS code :)